# I could see where I'd be your best shot

Tags: meaning

While I was watching the TV show *Friends*, there was a sentence that I couldn't understand.
Monica : Phoebe, you understand, don't you?
Phoebe : Well, I could see where I'd be your best shot, but no. I'm sorry. It's very twisted.
In this conversation, I can't understand the sentence, *I could see where I'd be your best shot*
Please switch that sentence into another sentence that's easier to understand, not changing the meaning.

Answer (score 1):

By context, Monica seems to have proposed some sort of scheme or plan or something. It's not clear what. I never watched Friends regularly. I think I've seen two full episodes and a bunch of fragments.

Phoebe is saying that she understands the situation. And that she can see it from Monica's point of view. And that from Monica's point of view, obtaining some kind of assistance from Phoebe will be Monica's greatest chance of success. However, Phoebe evaluates the situation as "very twisted." And so Phoebe rejects the plan.